# How can I select an output and set my configuration for pulse audio volume control from the terminal?

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I am working on a script that will disable both of my monitors and switch to my projector screen when it is turned on. So far, it works perfectly, except I have to change the audio output to that of the projector. In the pulse audio volume utility, I can do this by selecting "Digital Stereo (HDMI 6) Output (unplugged)" under the configuration for my GPU (Ellsmere Radeon RX 580) and then selecting my GPU in the playback tab. Is there a way that I can automate this so that it is all handled automatically in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicaly you have to move your audio stream from one output to another.

List available outputs

`$ pactl list short sinks`

```
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_67_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

List all running audio stream

`$ pactl list short sink-inputs`

```
1716    0   915 protocol-native.c   s16le 1ch 44100Hz
1717    0   916 protocol-native.c   s16le 1ch 44100Hz
1719    0   918 protocol-native.c   s16le 1ch 44100Hz
2059    0   14  protocol-native.c   float32le 2ch 48000Hz
2067    0   1152    protocol-native.c   s16le 2ch 44100Hz
2078    0   14  protocol-native.c   float32le 2ch 48000Hz
```

Move each stream to new output using :

```
$ pactl move-sink-input <stream_id> <output_id>
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks! This solved it!